# How many triangles are there?

Tags: puzzle

Some time ago I found a puzzle and it stopped my work until I solved it.

[image]

One of the possible solutions:

Let us sum upright and upside down triangles whose top lies in the $i$-th row.
$$
N=\sum_{i=1}^n N_i^\Delta + N_i^\nabla.
$$

For upright triangles we should multiply the number of possible sizes $n-i+1$ by the number of possible horizontal positions $i$
$$
N_i^\Delta = (n-i+1)i.
$$
An upside down triangle with size $l$ at $i$-th row have $n-i-l+1$ positions and the size $l$ limited by $\min(i,n-i)$, therefore
$$
N_i^\nabla = \sum_{l=1}^{\min(i,n-i)}(n-i-l+1).
$$

Finally, we have
$$
N=\sum_{i=1}^n\Bigl((n-i+1)i+\sum_{l=1}^{\min(i,n-i)}(n-i-l+1)\Bigr).
$$

For $n=28$ rows we get $N=5985$ triangles.

My question is: could you suggest a less trivial solution, which can reveal the power of the different sides of *Mathematica*? I mean look at this problem from different sides: finding a sequence, image-processing, finding a cycles in a graph and so on.

Comment: Don't forget the five in the legend, the two green ones on each side, and the three A's in the title. ;)

Comment: There is a formula [n(n+2)(2n+1)]/8
Where n is no of rows

Comment: A trivial solution would be adding the first 28 triangle numbers (from 1 to 406 which total is 4060), that represents the number of triangles up.
The you have to add the same triangle numbers but skipping one (1, 6, 15, 28..378, which total is 1925) that represents the triangles down) So total number of triangles are 4060+1925=5985

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Edit faster version..

```
 n = 10
 pt = Flatten[Table[ {(j - i/2 - 1/2), -i (Sqrt[3]/2)}, { i, n}, {j, i} ], 1];
 isegs = GatherBy[ Select[ Subsets[pt, {2}] , 
            IntegerQ[(3/Pi) ArcTan @@ (Subtract @@ #)] & ], Norm[Subtract @@ #] & ];
 all = Flatten[
        Union@Select[Union@Flatten[#, 1] & /@ Subsets[#, {2}] , 
          Length[#] == 3 && 
             Norm[#[[2]] - #[[1]]] ==
             Norm[#[[3]] - #[[1]]] == 
             Norm[#[[2]] - #[[3]]] &] & /@ isegs, 1];

  Export["test.gif", Graphics[{Polygon[# ],Point@pt}] & /@ all ]
```

[image]

```
 Length@all
```

> 235

This returns the 5985 value in reasonable time.
Note by the way for a large enough grid you pick up integer length point distances that are not aligned with the grid.

Comment: Thank your for participating, your visualization is really nice!

Answer (score 16):

I don't really know what kind of answer you expect here. Your answer is obviously the smart way.

Brute force is always an option though:

```
trianglePoints[n_] := Module[{p = {}, s = 1},
  Do[Do[AppendTo[p, {a + b/2, Sqrt[0.75] b}], {b, 0, n + 1 - s}]; 
   s++;, {a, 1, n + 1}]; p]

res = Select[Subsets[trianglePoints[28], {3}], 
   Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] == Norm[#[[1]] - #[[3]]] == Norm[#[[2]] - #[[3]]] &&
     Length@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@#[[{1, 3}]] == 3 &];
Length@res
```

> 5985

By the way, there are many more equilateral triangles to find. Check this example:

```
res2 = Select[Subsets[trianglePoints[3], {3}], 
   Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] == Norm[#[[1]] - #[[3]]] == 
     Norm[#[[2]] - #[[3]]] &];
Grid[
 Partition[
  Graphics[{GrayLevel[0.5], 
      Triangle[{{1, 0}, {3, 4*Sqrt[0.75]}, {5, 0}}], 
      RGBColor[RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]], 
      Triangle[#]}] & /@ res2
, 4]]
```

[image]

Comment: Given that lines are drawn already on the original puzzle, I would think it's asking only to count the triangles that can be formed with the existent lines.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: Why did you specify `AspectRatio -> 1`? That makes the triangles not remain equilateral.

Comment: @Rahul thanks, fixed.

Comment: Nice capture of the hidden symmetry (rotated triangles)!

Answer (score 16):

## MorphologicalBranchPoints

By "less trivial" I mean *everything* related to the problem. Let me give an example. One can consider this problem as an image-processing problem and calculate the number of triangles directly from the picture (the cropped one).

```
thin = Thinning@ColorNegate@Binarize@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhqI9.png"
```

[image]

```
points = Dilation[#, 1] &@MorphologicalBranchPoints@thin
```

[image]

```
p = ComponentMeasurements[MorphologicalComponents@points,"Centroid"][[All, 2]];
Graphics@Point[p]
```

[image]

We get nice positions of the corners. Now it remains to find all possible equilateral triangles with one horizontal side. Here `10` is the threshold in pixels

```
nrst = Nearest[p];

snap = With[{p1 = +##/2 + {0, #2[[1]] - #[[1]]} Sqrt[3]/2}, 
    With[{np = nrst[p1][[1]]}, 
     If[Norm[np - p1] < 10, {np, ##, np}, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]]] &;

triangles = 
  Flatten[{snap @@ #, snap @@ Reverse@##} & /@ 
    Select[Subsets[p, {2}], Abs[#[[1, 2]] - #[[2, 2]]] < 10 &], 1];

Graphics@Line@triangles
```

[image]

```
Length@triangles
```

> 5985

Comment: Great answer to your own question ! Maybe you want to thank the other participants ?

Comment: simpler way to get the points from the image: `p = ComponentMeasurements[Binarize@CornerFilter@Import@"http://i.stack.imgur.com/vhqI9.png" //ImageAdjust, "Centroid"][[All, 2]];`

Comment: @eldo, I ask this question not for the answer as a number or a formula. I ask it for different ideas and approaches. It is very fascinating and allows to learn something new for me and another participants. My answer is just an example. It is not a "final answer". It would be great to take another answers!

Comment: @paw Yes, indeed! It is an interesting filter.

Comment: I think you can replace `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` with `##&[]` or `Sequence@@{}`. The former is obviously more terse.